# Match string followed by another string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression newbie question.
I am trying to do a case insensitive search in a string. I need to search `cgif` followed by any text and ending in `.txt` but the code below does not work. What am I missing?

```
using System;   
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rx = new Regex("(cgif)+(.txt)+^", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool x1=rx.IsMatch("abc\\cgif123.txt");
        Console.WriteLine($"{x1}");<=should return true
        
        bool x2=rx.IsMatch("abc\\cgif.txt");
        Console.WriteLine($"{x2}");<=should return true
        
        bool x3=rx.IsMatch("abc\\cgif.txtabc");
        Console.WriteLine($"{x3}");<=should return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What regex tutorial did you follow? Use `@"cgif.*\.txt$"` with `| RegexOptions.Singleline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```cs
var rx = new Regex(@"cgif.*\.txt$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

NOTES:

- `RegexOptions.Singleline` - will make `.` match newlines, LF, chars, too
- `cgif.*\.txt$` matches `cgif`, then any zero or more chars as many as possible, and then `.txt` at the end of string.

Here is a [demo showing how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/sFn3qc/1). Also, see the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/xgnTb1) yielding `True, True, False` as expected.

Comment: @Joel `\[.]` matches a `[`, then any char and then a `]`. To match a dot, one needs `\.`.

Comment: You may also want to add case insensitivity in your RegexOptions to make it complete